# Travelling to the UK with EU family Permit without my EU partner

Tags: eu

I recently applied for the EU family permit to travel to the UK with my wife and kids who are EU citizens. The permit came after the planned date of our holiday. And now I want to make a short trip to the UK without the wife and kids, because they have resumed school. Is is possible that I travel alone without my wife? Or is it okay to take my wife's EU passport along with me to show?

Answer (score 3):

> **Is is possible that I travel alone without my wife.**

No (since she is not in the UK already)

> **Or is it okay that I take my wife EU passport along with me to show.**

No

---

### General Principle

Generally, if the premise of your visit has changed, you can't use visas or other documents obtained for a different premise.

---

### Family-Permit Conditions

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area_Family_Permit):

> A family permit will be issued if the applicant is the spouse, civil partner or dependent child of an EEA national **and they will be travelling to the UK with that person**

The [UK government say](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility):

> The EEA citizen you’re joining must either:
>
> - be in the UK already
> - **be travelling with you** to the UK within 6 months of the date of your application

(my emphasis in both quotations above)

Travelling with your wife's passport is not the same as travelling with your wife.

---

### Conclusion

As a (presumably) non-EU national you need to apply for an appropriate visa if one is required for your nationality.